# Class not found exception

Tags: java, reflection, classnotfoundexception

I am learning reflection in Java. I came to know that we can easily extract methods used in a class file with reflection.

I have a java class file which has n number of methods.

Test file refers to the java class from where I want to read the methods used and testSample is my class from where I am accessing Testfile class methods

```
 public class testSample
    {

        public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException

        {

            File filename = new File(
                    "C:/ProgramData/Eclipse/Projects_3.7.1/Testfile.java");

            String filen = filename.toString();

            if (filen.endsWith(".java"))

            {

                String actfilename = StringUtils.substringBefore(filen, ".java");

                Class classname = Class.forName(actfilename);

                Method[] method = classname.getMethods();

                for (Method methods : method)

                {

                    System.out.println("Method name \r\n" + methods.getName());

                    Class[] parameters = methods.getParameterTypes();

                    for (Class parametername : parameters)

                    {

                        System.out.println("parameters name \r\n"
                                + parametername.getName());

                    }

                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Please help me out of this.

Exception error I am getting is as follows

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: testFile
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at com.TestSample1.retrievemethods(TestSample1.java:58)
    at com.TestSample1.filetraverse(TestSample1.java:43)
    at com.TestSample1.filetraverse(TestSample1.java:45)
    at com.TestSample1.main(TestSample1.java:22)
```

TestFile

Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestions. But I'm still not out of it.

Let me make it clear.

```
static File appname="C:/programdata/eclipse/appname";

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException 

{

        TestSample1 tf1=new TestSample1();

        tf1.filetraverse(appname);

}

public void filetraverse(File appname) throws ClassNotFoundException

{

        if (appname.isDirectory()) 

        {

            File[] files = appname.listFiles();

            for (File filename : files) 

            {

                    String finame=filename.getName().toLowerCase();

                    if(finame.endsWith("java"))

                    {

                            retrievemethods(filename,reflection);

                    }           

                            filetraverse(filename);     

            }           

        }

    }

public void retrievemethods(File filename,File reflection) throws 
ClassNotFoundException

    {

        String classna=filename.toString();

        String classnam=StringUtils.substringBetween(classna, "/appname/", ".java");

        Class reflectclass = Class.forName(classnam);

        Method[] method=reflectclass.getMethods();

        for (Method methods : method)

        {

            System.out.println("Method name \r\n"+methods.getName());

        Class[] parameters=methods.getParameterTypes();

        for (Class parametername : parameters) 

        {

            System.out.println("parameters name \r\n"+parametername.getName());

        }

    }

    }
```

and the error I am getting is class not found exception.

Comment: What is the content of  `actfilename`

Comment: "I came to know that we can easily extract methods used in a class file" `foo.java` is not class file, `foo.class` is. Also you need to have location of package of class you want to use in classpath, or load it with ClassLoader.

Answer (score 0):

Your program will not work unless you have compiled class on Classpath.

Also the argument of `Class.forName(String)` is **expecting Fully Qualified Name of the class on classpath, not the file path**.

Comment: I have two class files in my package. One is testfile, another testsample,

Class classname=TestSample2.class;
This will work for the case if the TestSample2 is in same package. 

Bot how can I retrieve the class name if it is in different package.?
How can we pass the file whole path to get respective class name ?

"C:/ProgramData/Eclipse/Projects_3.7.1/TestSample2.java"

Comment: Please describe your directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class classname = Class.forName(actfilename);
```

Here 'actfilename' should be the fully qualified class name.

Eg:
Required Class Name - `com.organisation.reflection.Testfile`
Your Class Name - `Testfile`

When you make a call to Class.forName("sampleClass"), JVM dynamically loads the class at runtime and returns the Class object associated with the "sampleClass".

For Eg:

```
package com.organisation.reflection;

class TestFile {

static {

    System.out.println("TestFile class loaded.");
}
```

}

```
package com.organisation.reflection;

public class TestSample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try { 
        Class c   = Class.forName("com.organisation.reflection.TestFile"); 
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    }

}
```

}

Output:

TestFile class loaded.

[Check Class.forName here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_forname.htm)

Comment: Where can we find .class file for a .java when working in eclipse ?

Comment: The problem is that it works fine for a single class. If i have n number of class files in a folder, unable to read them all

Comment: Go to your project folder and within go to your target folder. There you will find the jar/war file and a folder named 'Classes'. Go the the 'Classes' folder. There you will find all your classes in package hierarchy.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many class files present in a single folder. For Eg: Sample1.java, Sample2.java & Sample3.java are present in same package, i.e. com.organisation.reflection. In order to load all the aforementioned three class, you have to call Class.forName() three times with the fully qualified names of all the three classes. Class.forName("com.organisation.reflection.Sample1") Class.forName("com.organisation.reflection.Sample2") Class.forName("com.organisation.reflection.Sample3")

Comment: The method will be like this
public void retrievemethods(File filename,File reflection) 
throws ClassNotFoundException
 
{

  Class reflectclass = Class.forName(filename);

  Method[] method=reflectclass.getMethods();

  for (Method methods : method)

  {

   System.out.println("Method name 

\r\n"+methods.getName());

  Class[] parameters=methods.getParameterTypes();

  for (Class parametername : parameters) 

  {
System.out.println("parameters name"+parametername.getName());

 }
}
error occurs at Class reflectclass = Class.forName(filename); as we can pass only string as parameter not a file

Answer (score 0):

Hurrayy... Finally got it.. :) :)  :D :D
Thanks a lot ppl... :) :)

```
public void retrievemethods(File filename,File reflection) throws ClassNotFoundException  
    {
        Class c=filename.getClass();
        Method[] method=c.getMethods();
        for (Method methods : method) 
        {
            System.out.println("new methods"+methods);
        }
    }
```

Comment: But of no use.. :( 
Guess what the output was .. :(

It just displays the file operation methods like
getabsolutepath, get canonicalpath, etc... :( :(